# Prove that there are at least $4(p-3)(p-1)^{p-4}$ functions $f:S\to S$ satisfying $\sum \limits_{x\in T} x^{f(x)}\equiv a \pmod p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

This question is the third round of Iranian exam questions, which has not been answered for several years now. I think there are many people here, which may be able to solve this problem.

From [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h429050p2427931)

> **Problem:**
>
> $a$ is an integer and $p$ is a prime number and we have $p\ge 17$. Suppose that $S=\{1,2,....,p-1\}$ and $T=\{y|1\le y\le p-1,\operatorname{ord}_p(y)<p-1\}$. Prove that there are at least $4(p-3)(p-1)^{p-4}$ functions $f:S\longrightarrow S$ satisfying
> $$\sum_{x\in T} x^{f(x)}\equiv a \pmod p$$

It seems that this problem can be solved by generating function, but I don't know how to start. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by $\operatorname{ord}_p(y)$?

Comment: Isn't $T=\{y|1 \leq y \leq p-1\}$

Comment: @Servaes,$ord_{p}(y)$ is the order of $y$ moddulo $p$

Comment: The multiplicative order, the additive order, or some other order?

Comment: the smallest postive integer $d$ for which $n|a^d-1$ is called the order of $a$ modulo $n$..

Comment: will not the number of functions depend on the nature of $a$ here?

Comment: In addition, is there any restriction on the nature of functions: like continuous, or injective, bijective etc.

Comment: It obviously can't be continuous since it's from a finite set w/o topology to another finite set w/o topology. There's no idea for continuous in this case.

Answer (score 0):

first if you don't have the restriction $ord(y)<p-1$ you can choose $p-2$ elements arbitary and choose $f(g)$(g is an primary root) such that the equality work.the best think after $g$ is $g^{\pm 2}$ so choose f of other elements arbitary and choose f of this two elements such that the equality works this gave the problem bound.